# Optimal way for django template to get random line from included file

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to add a random slogan to my base template.  I realize the easy way to do this is to have a db table with my slogans, get a random one, and pass it to the template.

The question is, how do I do it without using the db?  In my base template, I want to include a file with a bunch of slogans, one on each line, and have the template randomly pick one.  I know the `random` filter will pick a random value from a list, so somehow, I need to `include` the slogan file, but as a list.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use a flat file over the database?

Comment: The slogans will change rarely and there are only a few of them.  Even with db caching, it seems like an unnecessary complication to create and maintain a separate app (or to "dirty" an irrelevant existing app) in order to put a sentence on every page header.  To me, the logical place should be in my `header.inc` being included in my `base.html` template.

Comment: My thoughts are that if there is a function choosing a slogan at random, the database would be much more efficient at handling it than using a flat file. I know the call to the db can be cached, but can the call to your slogans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options I see:

1) Use a context-processor to load this random quote (i.e. from a flat file), then insert into context. Example:

```
# create your own context-processor file (myutils/context_processors.py)
def my_random_quote_processor(request):
    context = {}

    # generate your string you want in template
    # ....
    context['RANDOM_QUOTE'] = my_random_quote

    return context


# in settings.py, tell django to include your processor
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # ...,
    'myutils.context_processors.my_random_quote_processor'
)


# in your base template, just include the template var
<p>quote: {{ RANDOM_QUOTE }}</p>


# make sure in your views, you set the context_instance
def my_view(request):
    # ...
    return render_to_response('myapp/mytemplate.html', c, 
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

2) Create a custom template-tag where you load the quote from a flat file, etc.: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Thanks!  For (1):  Since I'd like to include the slogan in my `header.inc` and therefore on every page, was hoping to avoid including an extra variable because I have different views passing different contexts, making this route complicated.  For (2):  See my reply to Loarfatron--I guess this is the way to go if there isn't a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I would vote for a template tag.  Store the random quote in a text file with each quote on a separate line.  Then in the template tag read in a line at random, a nice explanation of how to do that here:
http://www.regexprn.com/2008/11/read-random-line-in-large-file-in.html.
Reproduced below:

> ```
> import os,random
>
> filename="averylargefile" file =
> open(filename,'r')
>
> #Get the total file size file_size = os.stat(filename)[6]
>
> while 1:
>   #Seek to a place in the file which is a random distance away
>   #Mod by file size so that it wraps around to the beginning
>   file.seek((file.tell()+random.randint(0,file_size-1))%file_size)
>
>   #dont use the first readline since it may fall in the middle of a line
>   file.readline()
>   #this will return the next (complete) line from the file
>   line = file.readline()
>
>   #here is your random line in the file
>   print line
> ```
>
> Finally return the line so your template tag can print it out.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like it should work, if I was to use this method of manually reading from a file.  However, this really seems like going "behind django's back" :)  If there's no way to do what I want "the django way," maybe by doing something special with the `include` tag, I suppose this is the way to go.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about a more djangoey way to do it.  Out of curiosity why do you want to keep the slogans out of the db?  Having it in the database would make it easy to update/add slogans through the admin.

Answer (score 0):

If your slogans base is pretty small you can use pickle module.
And operate your base like a normal list.
http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

But i think the best solution is to keep your slogans database in real db

Comment: Could you be more specific?  How would I use pickle from a template?  It seems like I'd still have to pass a pickled list to the template, at which point I may as well pass in a regular list and use the `random` filter.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out this snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2121/ 
will solve it.